# SSHD user account and users folder

Tags: windows-7

Under `C:\Users` folder there is a `SSHD` user (created probably during openSSH server installation). When i issue `net users` there is no such `SSHD` user. What is the `SSHD` user and why it's not listed by the above command?

Answer (score -2):

If its not listed on net user, that means its either left over or is renamed, so the best advise is to not touch it, It doesnt take alot of storage place. The SSHD user is just a user created by openssh, dont delete the folder as openssh may try to use it again. Its not listed because, as i said, the user is either deleted or renamed.

Comment: If a user renamed their account the User folder name would not change. This is poor advise.